# Android Handler updates TextView only with last setText()

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-handler

The following code is from Head First Android. It is for a stopwatch app.

I have a few questions in the following code:

1. The code runs like -> OnCreate -> runTimer() (skips handler.post()) -> OnStart -> onResume -> Comes back to handler.post().

Why does it skip `hander.post()` in the first place?

2. I have two textView.setText(). But the first one doesn't work. It's always the last one. I put the second one just to see what the code does after postDelay() method.

Why doesn't the first one work? I am expecting the text to jump back and forth from "hello" to "hh:mm:ss".

3. So what exactly happens during the 1-second delay after postdelay() is executed.

Does the code starts running normally and when its 1 second the postDelay() is called?

4. why is this used in postDealy(this, 100). shouldn't it be `this.run()`?

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {       
       private boolean running = false;
       private int counter = 0;
       private Handler handler = new Handler();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           runTimer();
       }

       public void onClickStart(View view){
           running = true;
       }

       public void runTimer(){
           final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

           handler.post(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {
                   int hours = counter/3600;
                   int minutes = (counter%3600)/60;
                   int secs = counter%60;

                   String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);
                   textView.setText(time); // Doesn't set it to this - see last line 

                   if(running){
                       counter++;
                   }
                   handler.postDelayed(this,1000); // what does happens between next one second 
                   textView.setText("hell0"); // Always set it to this 
               }

           });
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it skip `hander.post()` in the first place?

It is not skipped, it will be executed after `onResume()` returns. All the `Runnable`s, queued though a Handler associated with the main thread, start their execution only after `onResume()` returns.

> Why doesn't the first one work?

It does work. You just can't visually see it because the two method calls, `textView.setText()`, are invoked "almost" at the same time.

The following sequence of calls happen at each `run()`:

- `textView.setText(time)`,
- the same `Runnable` is posted to the queue with `handler.postDelayed(this,1000)`. Immediately after that
- `textView.setText("hell0")` is called

> Why doesn't the first one work? I am expecting the text to jump back and forth from "hello" to "hh:mm:ss".

You should implement an extra logic to switch between *time* and *"hell0"* at each `run()` execution.

*E.g. create a boolean flag in the Activity and set either time or "hell0" depending on the flag value (don't forget to change the flag value at each `run()` execution)*.

> why is this used in postDelay(this, 100). shouldn't it be `this.run()`?

No, `this.run()` is executed synchronously (and immediately) and is of type *void*. The code won't compile as [postDelay()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%2520long)) expects the *Runnable* type, not *void*.

Comment: You are right the value is set to `HH:MM:SS` after `textView.setText(time)`. But it is not upated in the GUI. I checked by adding breakpoints. After executing `textView.setText(time)`, the GUI still displays `Helloo` even though the value of texview is set to `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: @lynxx, you won't see `HH:MM:SS` on UI when setting a breakpoint "After executing `textView.setText(time)`" cause the main thread is stopped and `TextView` cannot update its layout. Simply create a flag boolean in the `Activity` and set either `time` or `"hell0"` depending on the flag value (don't forget to change the flag value at each `run()`). After that things become clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

`handler.postDelayed(this,1000);`

This used to run your function after 1 second.  It is a delay for 1 second.

The code written in your `handler` will execute after a second. That's all.